# Deploying [NodeJS file written in Typescript] on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, git, heroku

My NodeJS App is written in Typescript and I am trying to deploy it on Heroku.

I was following a YouTube tutorial.

My app is deployed but it's showing me error. Can anybody tell me what's the issue?

Is it because of the app written in Typescript?

I created a Procfile and added this [web: nodemon src/server.ts] in file. So that heroku knows where to find the server file.

If there is a similar question or answer related to my Question, please do share that link here.

Comment: I'm doing an app in express-node with typescript and i can relate to this question, and, as far as i know, shouldn't you put in the procfile document server.js instead of server.ts ?

Comment: @Diego I am new to tyepscript and node, the whole back is written in typescript with extensions ".ts" including the server file. That's why i put server.ts

Comment: @Diego TypeScript files are `.ts` files. I don't know why OP isn't just compiling the TypeScript into JavaScript beforehand tho

Comment: #1 Could you share us the package.json to have an idea of your stack? #2 How do you run in your laptop? `npm run dev`  #3 Do you have the `npm run build` script in your package.json? #4 `npm run build` is required to make real js apps using javascript or typescript. #4 If you have this script, I created a server which would help you to deploy your js app in any server like heroku, gcp, aws, azure, etc

Comment: Thanks @JRichardsz  for your response, i ran the "npm run build" command, it created a folder named "dist", but it doesn't contain any package.json file. So, I have to deploy this folder?

Comment: In the main directory there should be a package.json, share it

Comment: "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/server.ts",
    "build": "sucrase ./src -d ./dist --transforms typescript,imports"
  },

can't post whole file here.

Comment: #1 react and sucrase are an open source technologies. Don't be afraid to share parts of your code. Of course hide or delete sensitive  or private information.  #2 Share the content of your dist folder. #3 Test if your dist files are a valid web: index.html, css, js, fonts, etc. If you are in linux, open a shell pointing to dist folder and start a minimal http server with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`, after that open in your browser `http://localhost:8000` to verify if your app looks like the development version.

Comment: Thank you Guys, for your response. I found the answer and posted it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

First add all of your config variables in App settings on Heroku.
The second is to add your [start and engine] scripts in package.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/server",
    "dev": "sucrase-node src/server.ts",
    "build": "sucrase ./src -d ./dist --transforms typescript,imports"
  },enter code here
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: I had to change the `"start": "node dist/server"` to `"start": "node ./server"`. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Answer

My script package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --no-notify --respawn --transpile-only src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc --build",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "deloy": "git push heroku main",
    "log": "heroku logs --tail"
  },
```

my Procfile
`web: npm start`